# AWS EC2-Routing outgoing traffic through a single public IP in a EC2-Classic environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Our `EC2` instances are not inside a `VPC`.
We have multiple web servers (`EC2` instances) which want to communicate to a third party service (via API) through a single public IP.
We cant use a NAT gateway provided by `AWS` because that can only be used with `VPC`.

What are the possible approaches to achieve this?

Basically I am looking for a forward proxy type thing which needs to be configured for the web servers, so that the egress traffic seems to come from a single public IP.

Comment: could we know why you don't use a vpc?

Comment: You're going to struggle to get advice about pre-VPC AWS. If this is important you should probably get an AWS support contract and ask AWS - their support is fantastic when you pay for it.

Comment: Currently our complete infrastructure lies in ec2-classic setup. Migrating to VPC would take quite some time and effort.

Comment: I wonder how much longer ec2-classic will be available. I think you should start planning to migrate before AWS decides to make ec2-classic unavailable.